# Chrome extensions: How can I pass form variables to a url in a newly created tab?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on my first chrome extension, and using an image-based context menu item to capture the URL of a given image, and want to then display that image at a specific URL in a new tab.  So, I need to pass the URL of the image clicked on (using srcUrl) to a specific script that can then render it on that page.  Is it possible to perform an HMLHttpRequest from within a chrome.tabs.create() call, or must this be done some other way?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create an HTML page containing that script and put it into your extension folder. Then you can just pass image url to it as GET parameter:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "local.html?img_url=...");
```

If url parameter is not enough, you would be also able to communicate with that page using `chrome.tabs.sendRequest()`:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "local.html", function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {img_url: "local.html?img_url=...");
));
```

With the request listener in that page:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request) {
    console.log(request.img_url);
});
```